# Camera lags when orientation is changed

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

I am trying to create a camera preview using `SurfaceView` and it mostly works fine. I initialize the camera on `onSurfaceCreated` method and destroy it on `onSurfaceDestroyed`. Why are the above methods being called when the orientation of the device changes. Following is the surface view code.

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // Initialize the camera
    initCamera();
    Log.d("tags", "Camera Started!");
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
    }
    Log.d("tags", "Camera destroyed!");
}

public void initCamera() {
    if (camera == null) {
        camera = Camera.open(); // Get's the first camera
    }

    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(sfHolder);
    } catch (IOException err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Set camera orientation
    Activity activity = (Activity)this.getContext();
    this.setCameraDisplayOrientation(activity);

    camera.startPreview();
}

private void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity) {

    Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);

    int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
    int degrees = 0;

    switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
    }

    int result;
    if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
        result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
    } else {  // back-facing
        result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
    }

    Log.d("tag", "Result -- " + result);
    boolean camNull = camera == null;
    Log.d("tag", String.valueOf(camNull));

    camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
```

When I launch the application on my device, the preview starts as expected but when I change the orientation from portrait to landscape and vice versa, the preview hangs for a few seconds and the new preview is shown with the changed orientation.

According to the logs surface is being destroyed and created again when orientation changes and hence the camera is being re-initialized everytime orientation changes. How can I overcome this ? Am I doing anything wrong here ?

Comment: One way to overcome this is to lock the activity in one orientation mode than detect orientation changes yourself and only changing the UI. This is how I do it, but I dont quite like it.